# Finché: tempo semplice o composto?

Tags: verbs

1."Non ci crederò finché non lo vedrò."

2. "Non ci crederò finché non lo avrò visto."

3."È stato criticato finché ha giocato in quella squadra."

4."È stato criticato finché giocava in quella squadra."

Sono legittimi sia i tempi semplici e composti? Soprattutto poi, sono intercambiabili nelle frasi stillate da me?

Chiaramente ci sarà qualche differenza di significato tra l'usare uno o l'altro, anche se io non le percepisco più di tanto.

Buona serata e grazie a tutti.